# Is ADB backup on a Chromebook somehow different than on PC?

Tags: adb, backup, linux, chromebook

I'm attempting to run `adb -t ...` dev# `... shell backup -nosystem` (with or without `-f ~/backup.bk`.  For some reason, nothing appears in the device notifications, and on the terminal side no error or other indication is given but the `bu help` text gets echoed back.  There is no file container created in the current directory, so I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong?

The device is a stock OnePlus 8T+ 5G TMO Unlocked (KB2007).  The Chromebook is a Lenovo Flex 3 Chrome-11M836 - Type 82KM (Jacuzzi board) with developer mode enabled (but I'm running adb through a Terminal instance rather than dev console/crosh).  Also, if it matters, I am attempting the backup through a Samsung T5 SSD (the system doesn't have enough storage capacity to handle the backup directly).

EDIT: the storage device is not directly mounted to Linux, it's instead mounted in CrOS then "share with Linux" is toggled on through `Files`.

Comment: `adb backup` is implement on Android side so it doesn't matter if you execute if from a PC or ChromeOS. Effectively adb calls the command `bu` on Android side and passes all the parameters to it. Your other questions are ChromeOS specific which means they are off-topic here.

Comment: @robert I was having trouble deciding, but would this question be a better fit over at SU?  Also, based upon what you're saying, would I need to rewrite the directory path as the *Android instance* would see it?  Honestly I've never even tried so I'm not sure if external storage is even accessible at all from within the Android environment, and if it were what the path would be if it does differ.  But then again, on a PC I recall I was able to directly specify the path of the container to a local directory?

Comment: Sorry but your remaining question are on ChromeOS not Android, thus I can not help you on that.